# How do I remove all lines that start with "border-radius"? (VS Code)

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

I want to remove all lines that starts "border-radius".

How to? Please help me.

Example my scss code is here.

```
.img-thumbnail {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.figure {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It's as simple as [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files)

Comment: Search `border-radius` and delete inline(Ctrl+X).

Comment: @ Helenesh Thank you! I'm really hard to study regex.

Comment: Did'n work only replace. @Jake

Comment: Yes, Just removed one line. @Mukyuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the search bar <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Enable the Regular Expression <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (*this will toggle the RegEx, so make sure the .* is highlighted in the corner of the search bar*)

Add this expression `^\s*border-radius`

Select All Occurrences of Find Match <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the search bar

Delete\Remove lines <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to escape multi-line selection

Hope this will help!